# Getting user infos using ObjectiveDropboxOfficial framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, dropbox

I am using ObjectiveDropboxOfficial framework for Dropbox integration within Objective-C app (due to the deprecation of v1 dropbox api).
[Framework link](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/)

I am trying to get logged in dropbox user info (email, name, etc). Here is my code:

```html
DropboxClient *client=[DropboxClientsManager authorizedClient];
    [[client.usersRoutes getCurrentAccount]
    response:^_Nonnull(DBUSERSBasicAccount *response, DBError *dberror)
     {
             // loginLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@\n%@", account.name, account.email];
             
             return response;
             
         }
     }];
```

This code doesn't work and additionnally causes weird error from xcode: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7CwZ.png)
The method definition is:

```html
    - (DBRpcTask<DBUSERSBasicAccount *, DBUSERSGetAccountError *> *_Nonnull)      getAccount:(NSString *_Nonnull)accountId;
```

```html
- (DBRpcTask<TResponse, TError> *_Nonnull)response:
    (void (^_Nonnull)(TResponse _Nullable, TError _Nullable,
                      DBError *_Nullable))responseBlock;
```

I was stuck with this for a whole day, any help would be appreciated:
1- How to get user infos using the framework, or
2- What is causing the error and how should that Nonnull method be called?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So finally after 2 days of struggling I found the response :

```
DropboxClient *client = [DropboxClientsManager authorizedClient];
if(client)
{


[[client.usersRoutes getCurrentAccount] response:^(DBUSERSFullAccount *account, DBNilObject *obj, DBError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error.errorContent);
    }

    if (account != nil) {
        NSLog(@"User's name %@", account.name.displayName);

    }
    if(self.hud)
    [self.hud hideAnimated:YES];
}];
```

I hope this would save another developer's energy and mental health :)

Comment: getCurrentAccount never returns for me with a valid client object, does this still work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. Is your user logged in successfully? What error did you get?

Comment: It ended up being an error with authorizedClient not being set correctly, working correctly now! Thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. If it helped, please do not forget to accept the answer, or vote for it :)